# File not found nginx php-fpm

Tags: php, nginx

I've looked through every question like this here and tried to apply the stated fixes with no success.

I'm using the `wordpress:4.7.3-php7.0-fpm-alpine` docker image with a separate nginx container in front of it.

When I curl wordpress I get:

```
File not found.
```

When I check the wordpress container logs, I get:

```
127.0.0.1 -  16/Mar/2017:06:26:24 +0000 "GET /index.php" 404
127.0.0.1 -  16/Mar/2017:06:31:27 +0000 "GET /index.php" 404
127.0.0.1 -  16/Mar/2017:06:32:16 +0000 "GET /index.php" 404
127.0.0.1 -  16/Mar/2017:06:37:17 +0000 "GET /index.php" 404
127.0.0.1 -  16/Mar/2017:06:39:09 +0000 "GET /index.php" 404
```

The actual nginx error is:

```
2017/03/16 06:26:24 [error] 17#17: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 10.128.0.7, server: k8wp, request
: "GET / HTTP/1.0", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000"
```

I'm using php 7

```
/var/www/html # php-fpm -v
PHP 7.0.16 (fpm-fcgi) (built: Mar  3 2017 23:07:56)
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.16, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
```

My nginx config is

```
server {
    root /app;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _localhost;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index   index.php;
            fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include         fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

I'm running nginx as the user `www-data`:

```
user www-data;
```

According to `/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf` the user and group are uncommented and set to `www-data`

Comment: what is the actual filepath you want to execute?

Comment: @SahilGulati in the wordpress container it's at /var/www/html/index.php in the nginx container it's at /app

Comment: Just read somewhere that from the format of the message, it's a php error and not an nginx one

Comment: Do you use a MySQL below your wordpress?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The error indicates that your `SCRIPT_FILENAME` is incorrect. Your comment:

> in the wordpress container it's at /var/www/html/index.php in the
>   nginx container it's at /app

suggests that `nginx` and `php-fpm` are seeing a different document root.

In which case, use:

```
fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME  /var/www/html$fastcgi_script_name;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to include `include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;`. It should fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The issue I had with this was that my wordpress install was in a subdirectory. So the /blog/ main index of wordpress would load, but none of the published blog entries or pages in deeper directories such as `/blog/wp-admin/` would load.

To fix this, I added this block:

```
location /blog {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;
        }
```

This is actually explained in ["Location Strategies" of the nginx wordpress recipes page](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/wordpress/).

Answer (score 0):

My issue was due to serving the website's folder from within user's home folder.

Once I moved it from `/home/ubuntu/my-website` to `/srv/my-website` all worked fine.